# How do I write values from a list of tuples to rows in a csv using python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have a CSV that looks something like this:

`Point ID,Northing,Easting,Elevation,Attributes,Feature Code,Combined Scale Factor`

`1000,5000000,400000,100,Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:DEPTH:2.5|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:COVER_TYPE:DIRT/GRASS|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:COMPANY:ABC|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:SIZE:10|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln, pipe_ln,0.999665`

As you can see, the `Attributes` column contains

`Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:DEPTH:2.5|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:COVER_TYPE:DIRT/GRASS|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:COMPANY:ABC|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln:SIZE:10|Pipe_ln:pipeline_ln`

from which I would like to extract `DEPTH:2.5`. (There are ~50 rows, depths varies from row to row)

So far my code is as follows:

```
field_list = []

with open(infile, 'rb') as raw_csv:
    reader = DictReader(raw_csv, delimiter=',')
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['DEPTH']

    with open(outfile, 'wb') as out_csv:
        writer = DictWriter(out_csv, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        headers = {}
        for header in writer.fieldnames:
            headers[header] = header
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in reader:
            if 'Pipe_ln' in row['Feature Code']:
                field_list.append(row['Attributes'].replace("|", ":").split(":"))
                writer.writerow(row)
        DEPT_vals = header_tuple(field_list)
```

Under DictReader, I manually add the `DEPTH` field then on the last line of my code, `header_tuple` is a function I wrote that results in a list of tuples in the form [('DEPTH', 2.5), ('DEPTH', 2.1), etc...]

I can't wrap my head around the proper way, or any way, to get the tuple depth values to write under the `DEPTH` header. Any suggestions? Am I taking unnecessary steps? (Someone suggested to me to extract the information I wanted from `ATTRIBUTES` into tuples so that's why I have them as such).